# Is it compile error in typescript language or not? let a = "Pakistan"; a=9;

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors

Is it compile error in typescript language or not?

let a = "Pakistan";

a=9;

console.log(a);

options:

1: compiler error on line 1

2:compiler error on line2

3:compiler error on line3

4 :No compiler error

Is it compile error in typescript language or not? please explain

Answer (score 0):

There should be no errors after compiling this line of code, but Typescript will alert you in your IDE, such as VSCode, with this message below:

Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.